# PHPPower Point-struggelling for setting the path for require_once

Tags: php, codeigniter, phppowerpoint

I'm using the PHPPowerPoint library from (http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/26621). So I downloaded the "class" folder which contailes all of the needed libraries and put it in the CodeIgniter framework (Source Files/application/libraries/phppowerpoint/classes) and in my model I'm using their 01simple.php test. so I am refrecing their libraries by:

```
/** PHPPowerPoint */
require_once __dir__ . '/../libraries/phppowerpoint/classes/PHPPowerpoint.php';


/** PHPPowerPoint_IOFactory */
require_once __dir__ . '/../libraries/phppowerpoint/classes/PHPPwerpoint/PHPPowerpoint.php';
```

but it keeps giving me the following error:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'PHPPowerPoint.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Project1\application\libraries\PHPPowerpoint\Classes\PHPPowerpoint\Slide.php
>   on line 30

Sorry if Im asking my question in this way; but here is the only way I can get help, so if you need more clarification, please let me know!

Thanks

---

In Slide.php which is from the library I have the following requires:

```
/** PHPPowerPoint */
require_once 'PHPPowerPoint.php';

/** PHPPowerPoint_Slide_Layout */
require_once 'PHPPowerPoint/Slide/Layout.php';

/** PHPPowerPoint_Shape */
require_once 'PHPPowerPoint/Shape.php';

/** PHPPowerPoint_Shape_RichText */
require_once 'PHPPowerPoint/Shape/RichText.php';

/** PHPPowerPoint_Shape_BaseDrawing */
require_once 'PHPPowerPoint/Shape/BaseDrawing.php';

/** PHPPowerPoint_Shape_Drawing */
require_once 'PHPPowerPoint/Shape/Drawing.php';

/** PHPPowerPoint_Shape_MemoryDrawing */
require_once 'PHPPowerPoint/Shape/MemoryDrawing.php';

/** PHPPowerPoint_IComparable */
require_once 'PHPPowerPoint/IComparable.php';

/** PHPPowerPoint_Shared_Font */
require_once 'PHPPowerPoint/Shared/Font.php';

/** PHPPowerPoint_Shared_String */
require_once 'PHPPowerPoint/Shared/String.php';
```

and "PHPPowerPoint" is the outside of the folder of "slide.php" and slide.php is indes of "PHPPowerPoint"

> I guess the problem is require_once 'PHPPowerPoint.php'; for which I
>   need to go one folder outside! and deleteing "PHPPowerPoint" for other requires! right?

Thanks

Comment: will be good if you show us the directory structure

Comment: I dont know what is the best way to show it; but I put the PHPPowerPoint libraries which is called "class" at the CodeIgniter framework (Source Files/application/libraries/phppowerpoint/classes) and my model which is calling this library is at (Source Files/application\models\My_model.php)

Comment: Alos on line 30 slide.php I have "require_once 'PHPPowerPoint.php';"

Comment: I dont knwo what "C:\xampp\php\PEAR" is!

Comment: The problem is in your side.php which you are not showing.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your side.php comment at first. Your comment has `PHPPowerPoint.php` but your code above shows it as  `PHPPowerpoint.php`

Comment: Thanks for helping I added in a new comment!

Comment: Please see my side.php in the new comment! and please let me know what is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by rename the PHPPowerPoint to PHPPowerpoint in PHPPowerpoint.php because the Foldername is not PHPPowerPoint ;)